# SQL Subquery returns more than one row error

Tags: sql

I have an assignment for a class that requires me to write a procedure in SQL that takes the raw HW and test scores and then calculates the percentage for each assignment as well as the total weighted average. The primary key in the table is the SSN of the student. The max score for each assignment is stored under the SSN = '0001' and the weight of the assignment is stored under SSN = '0002.' I am getting a "Subquery returns multiple rows" error and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. If someone could help me out I would really appreciate it.

```
SET hw1M = (SELECT hw1 FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE (SSN = '0001'));
SET hw1W = (SELECT hw1 FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE (SSN = '0002'));
SET hw2aM = (SELECT hw2a FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE (SSN = '0001'));
SET hw2aW = (SELECT hw2a FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE (SSN = '0002'));
SET hw2bM = (SELECT hw2b FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE (SSN = '0001'));
SET hw2bW = (SELECT hw2b FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE (SSN = '0002'));
SET MidtermM = (SELECT Midterm FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE (SSN = '0001'));
SET MidtermW = (SELECT Midterm FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE (SSN = '0002'));
SET hw3M = (SELECT HW3 FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE (SSN = '0001'));
SET hw3W = (SELECT HW3 FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE (SSN = '0002'));
SET FExamM = (SELECT FExam FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE (SSN = '0001'));
SET FExamW = (SELECT FExam FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE (SSN = '0002'));
SET HW1Pct = ((SELECT Hw1 FROM RAW_SCORES)/hw1M);
SET HW2aPct = ((SELECT Hw2a FROM RAW_SCORES)/hw2aM);
SET HW2bPct = ((SELECT Hw2b FROM RAW_SCORES)/hw2bM);
SET MidtermPct = ((SELECT Midterm FROM RAW_SCORES)/MidtermM);
SET HW3Pct = ((SELECT Hw3 FROM RAW_SCORES)/hw3M);
SET FExamPct = ((SELECT FExam FROM RAW_SCORES)/FExamM);
SET WeightedAverage = ((HW1Pct * hw1w) + (HW2Pct * hw2aw) + (HW2bPct * hw2bw) + (MidtermPct * Midtermw) + (HW3Pct * hw3w) + (FExamPct * FExamw));

 SELECT SSN, FName, LName, HW1Pct, HW2Pct, MidtermPct, HW3Pct, FExamPct FROM RAW_SCORES;
```

Comment: You are not thinking in sets

Answer (score 0):

Think this way --

All students

```
SELECT *
FROM RAW_SCORES
WHERE SSN NOT IN ('0002','0001')
```

AVG score of HW1

```
SELECT AGV(HW1)
FROM RAW_SCORES
WHERE SSN NOT IN ('0002','0001')
```

Percentage of avg for all students

```
SELECT SSN, HW1 / X.AVG_HW1 AS PERCENT_OF_AVG_HW1
FROM RAW_SCORES
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT AGV(HW1) AS AVG_HW1
  FROM RAW_SCORES
  WHERE SSN NOT IN ('0002','0001')
) AS X
WHERE SSN NOT IN ('0002','0001')
```

etc

> I know this is not exactly what your professor is asking for -- my point is not to do your homework for you but instead to help you understand how to approach this problem in SQL using sets instead of like you are programming a control oriented language.  So I give you one example of an expression this way and assume you can extend this to the expressions needed.